# Getting the value of a button when the button is clicked, javascript

Tags: javascript

I have buttons that I make with an each sentence in jade

```
each u in requests
    form.form-horizontal(method="post")
        input(type='button', value='Accept #{u.friend}', onclick='doAction(this.value)')
        input(type='button', value='Ignore #{u.friend}', onclick='doAction(this.value)')
```

When any button is pressed I want to know the value of the button in my js so I made this function

```
function doAction(value){
    console.log(value)
}
```

but when i press the button i always get that doAction is undefined, is there a way to define doAction before I press the button or get the value of the button in another way

Comment: you will absolutely use javascript and not jquery ? @Sunna Halldorsdottir

Comment: if you do {u.friend} why you can not put this in onclick action like doAction(u.friend) ?

Answer (score 0):

By doing :

```
each u in requests
    form.form-horizontal(method="post")
        input(type='button', value='Accept #{u.friend}', onclick='doAction(this)')
        input(type='button', value='Ignore #{u.friend}', onclick='doAction(this)')
```

and in you js :

```
function doAction(obj){
    console.log(obj.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qbh99gw1/1/) to get the value of button with JS

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="getValue(this.value)">
```

JS

```
function getValue(value){
    alert(value)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, maybe you're referecing the wrong js file in your document

```
each val in ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
    form.form-horizontal(method="post")
    input(type='button', value='Accept #{val}', onclick='doAction(this.value)')
    input(type='button', value='Ignore #{val}', onclick='doAction(this.value)')
```

JS:

```
function doAction(value){
    alert(value);
}
```

[demo](https://jsbin.com/hukivadefu/edit?html,js,output)